# Next value of the decrements sequence

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario have to get the next decrements sequence.

Example of scenario i attached the below image.
[image]

My output i have given the image it is base on the 
1. Statuseq should decrements then the other values.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT taskNumber, assignedTo, statusSeq

FROM

( SELECT (@statusPre > statusSeq) AS statusChanged

, taskNumber, assignedTo, statusSeq

, @statusPre := statusSeq

FROM task

, (SELECT @statusPre:=NULL) AS d

where taskNumber = 'R3-09-5352'

ORDER BY endDate asc

) AS good

WHERE statusChanged;